# jQuery Mobile Panel Navigation

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm really new to this, so I may just be missing something, but is it possible to do a facebook type navigation that slides from the left/right with jQuery Mobile 1.4? I've found a lot of tutorials for previous versions, but it appears that 1.4 doesn't support them anymore. I can't find anything like this: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/pages/popup/popup-panels.html in the documentation/demos for 1.4. Do I need to use a plugin instead of jQuery Mobile's components?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: jQM 1.4 still has the panel widget: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/panel/

Comment: I tried using the panels for this, but absolutely nothing will work. Is there maybe something wrong with my links? http://imgur.com/rzBUTFf

Comment: you are pointing at very old versions of jQuery (1.5) and jQuery mobile (1.04alpha).  You should use at least jQuery 1.9 and release of jQM 1.4. Go to bottom of http://jquerymobile.com/ to see proper CDN links

Comment: Oh God. Thank you. I'm still having some issues with the nav bar, however. I'm using the facebook tutorial posted below. I copied the js entirely and made sure to link the .js file into my header. I'm trying to get the right button in my header to open the side menu... pictures: http://imgur.com/r4br6Z6,mbNxEQU

Comment: Here is an example using the panel: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/4Ch7z/

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely possible.

Here is a useful tutorial that I used to accomplish that behavior:

http://blog.aldomatic.com/2012/05/04/facebook-style-slide-out-menu-in-jquery-mobile/

It worked for me with JQM 1.4

Comment: I've tried this tutorial and many others. I can't seem to get anything to work. Is there a problem with my header links? http://imgur.com/rzBUTFf